# What's the best setup to transfer a digital or analog video over 100 ft?

Tags: cable, digital, analog, connectors

I'm looking for the best (price/quality) solution to send a digital or analog video signal to an lcd tv or beamer over 80 - 100 ft. The input can be hdmi, vga or dvi (all must be possible). The output (80 - 100 ft. away) doesn't need HD quality.

tv has hdmi, vga, dvi, s-video, composite and coax.

So far i've got this setup in mind for relative low cost and acceptable quality:

- 80-100 ft. vga cable connected to tv (should cover inputs with vga or dvi)
- vga switch 1-4 for switching between inputs
- hdmi --> vga converter (to cover hdmi inputs)

Does anyone know a better setup ?
is vga the best option in this case to bridge the 80-100 ft. ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A long VGA cable with a proper amp/spliter on the TX side, would be the simplest option. You can get good VGA cables up to 150' at modest prices from http://www.pccables.com .

Another good option is a CAT5 extender kit.
http://milestek.com/p-16209-vga-over-cat5ecat6-decora-wall-plate-set.aspx

Without a more detailed description of what you are trying to accomplish, it's hard to give a better answer than that.